# Could not resolve dependency for 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, android-gradle-3.0

I am trying to add firebase authentication to my project. I am getting following errors while syncing `build.gradle`:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3.
```

My app level gradle file is below:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'


        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The project level gradle file is :

```
 buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
 maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: add  `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in project level gradle

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the result is same @Sniffer

Comment: You are adding FireBase in new or existing project? And are you adding your google-services.json file in your App directoty?

Comment: yes of course sir, I've added google-services.json . This is an existing project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `project level gradle` file try to update **google-services plugin** to latest version:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // update version
    }
}
```

Comment: `jitpack.io` does not serve these dependencies; because this is the repository for `GitHub`. updating the Google Services plugin does appear way more likely.

Answer (score 2):

it complains about lack of dependencies for the `debugUnitTest`, while you don't have any `debug` build-type specified in your module-level `build.gradle`. it should look about like this, for example:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        renderscriptDebuggable true
        pseudoLocalesEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }
```

also, consider adding `androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2"` as a dependency ...and maybe add `testBuildType "debug"` to the `defaultConfig`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the normal way doesn't work,and assuming you are using Android Studio you could try using the GUI way by:

1. Clean Project
2. Rebuild Project
3. Under the `Tools`, select Firebase
4. Authentication
5. Email and password authentication
6. Connect to Firebase
7. Add dependencies
8. Check your auth status as described